# Conditions at the 10AU border of an Active Galactic Nucleus

Tags: space, galactic

Imagine that a ordinary human being was suddenly teleported to a distance 10AU from the center of the Milky Way. What would happen to them (in terms of things like pressure, temperature, radiation, stellar activity, etc.)?

I'm asking because I want to design a space station for my universe at that distance and need help understanding what the universe is like that close to the nucleus before I do.

Comment: Hi @Saucy, welcome.. could you focus on the proximity-question please ? there are two different questions now, a "level of technical knowledge" is relative.. and difficult to find an answer for.

Comment: I reworded the main question in the second paragraph. Is this along the lines of what you were looking for?
Edit: Upon a second read, I realize it is still too vague

Comment: Ok, I'll split this question up into two. Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that Milky Way's Sagittarius A* (as presently observed) is NOT an active galactic nucleus. So is this question about Sagittarius A* or some other, more active AGN?

Comment: @Alexander The question is asking about the Milky Way's nucleus (think, "center of the galaxy"). Saucy, it's simple and to the point. I've retracted my vote and upvoted. I've edited the question to add the reason you're asking as that's a requirement when asking Real World questions (which this now is), but you'll notice that it's not changing the question at all. With a little luck one of our experts in celestial mechanics and astrophysics will be online soon and give you a lot of details.

Comment: Excellent edit @Codidact, thanks for the help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While Sgr A* is not currently an active galactic nucleus, it is believed to have an accretion disk accompanied by a larger reservoir of gas surrounding it, with the latter extending well beyond a radius of 10 AU. We know from Chandra x-ray data that there is $\sim10^7$ Kelvin gas extending to $\sim10^5R_S$ (or $\sim8000$ AU, with $R_S$ the Schwarzschild radius$^{\dagger}$). More recent observations with the Atacama Large Millimeter Array ([Murchikova et al. 2017](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.08289) have found a cooler disk of $\sim10^4$ Kelvin gas extending to $2\times10^5R_S$ - still easily encompassing your poor human.

The ALMA measurements yield a number density of $n\approx10^{6}$ cm$^{-3}$, or a mass density, assuming a primarily hydrogen disk, of $\rho\sim10^{-18}$ kg cm$^{-3}$. If we were to naively apply the ideal gas law, this results in a pressure of $P\approx10^{-7}$ Pascals. In short, you've got gas that is - by human standards - extremely hot and extremely diffuse. Given that 10 AU is close to the very center of this cool disk, I would expect the temperature to actually be significantly hotter - so perhaps closer to that $\sim10^7$ K gas from the x-ray observations.

This is maybe 5 orders of magnitude denser than the interplanetary medium and 3-4 orders of magnitude hotter (depending on how hot you think this part of the disk will be). The x-ray emission, of course, would likely be catastrophic - that's what going to kill you and whatever spacecraft you're on, rather than the ambient gas.

Some general relativistic effects would likely be measurable but not easily noticeable. Things like time dilation and redshift scale with distance $r$ by a multiplicative factor of
$$\sqrt{1-\frac{R_S}{r}}\approx1-\frac{1}{2}\frac{R_S}{r}$$
and the second term comes out to about 0.4% at 10 AU - certainly not catastrophic, but not invisible, so to speak.

---

$^{\dagger}$The Schwarzschild radius is
$$R_S=\frac{2GM}{c^2}$$
and comes out to $1.18\times10^{10}$ meters assuming a black hole mass of $M\sim4\times10^6M_{\odot}$.

Answer (score 3):

**Only 24g, and don't worry about temperature or radiation**

Gravity is proportional to the square of distance.

At 10 AU, gravity will be 100 times smaller than normal gravity from the sun.

Studies have estimated the super-heavy black hole in the milky way center has a mass of 3.7 million or 4.1 million solar masses. As a result, you'll get 4e6/100 = 40,000 times *Solar* gravity at the point where you teleport your person.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_Center

On Earth, at the distance we orbit the sun, the gravitational pull of the sun is only 0.0006 of the strength of the earth's gravity on the surface of the earth. So when teleported at 10 AU from the galaxy center we'd experience 0.0006 x 40,000 is a force of 24g. In free fall, you won't notice..

https://van.physics.illinois.edu/qa/listing.php?id=184

Temperature and radiation may be a much bigger issue.. near a black hole, you'll have 10 million degrees.

[image]

However, at 10Au you'll be far away from the Schwartzshield radius of the black hole:

*"Located 26,000 light-years from the Sun, our galaxy’s central black hole, Sagittarius A(star), has a radius about 17 times that of the Sun, meaning that it would sit well within Mercury’s orbit."*

https://astronomy.com/news/2020/04/how-much-space-does-a-black-hole-take-up

.. a distance of 10AU, far away from the Schwartzshield radius, will reduce the heat considerably.

Other potential issues, e.g. the Hawking radiation emitted,

[image]

This Hawking radiation is very low energy

*An evaporating black hole would be detectable from Earth only if it went off within the solar system, or at best no further away than the nearest star.*

[https://jila.colorado.edu/~ajsh/bh/hawk.html](https://jila.colorado.edu/%7Eajsh/bh/hawk.html)

Further reading..

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_thermodynamics

Comment: is the Newtonian approximation accurate at that distance?

Comment: I assume it does maintain the quadratic relation with distance..  and "approximation" means that the error is small. Again: gravity is your smallest problem at 10AU.. in free fall, you won't even notice a 24g pull.. when you approach the Black hole's accretion disk.. and eventually the Schwarzshild radius you'll collide into material orbiting the black hole.. but you'll probably evaporate before reaching that point !

Comment: Even though our galactic center is not an AGN, it is a significant source of gamma-ray radiation caused by accretion. Assuming that excessive gravity is not an immediate concern, I would say gamma-ray radiation would be the main concern for a human here.

Comment: @Goodies "approximation" when applied to an equation means that that the error is small in certain cases. 

Since this person is only ~100  Schwarzschild radii away I would imagine that there would be general relativistic effects, at mercury is is thousands of Schwarzschild radii away from the sun and still experiences relativistic effects. 

Agreed, at that distance gravity wouldn't be the problem, i just think that the Newtonian description of gravity might be inaccurate at that distance.

Comment: @Nyra the person is "teleported" at 10AU distance from the black hole, with zero speed. Which *relativistic effects* are we talking about ?

Comment: @Goodie General relativistic effects from Space-time curvature,  such as time dilation and length extension, Described by the [Schwarzschild metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric).

Comment: @Nyr just a link to wiki won't do. I explained in my answer, the orbit Mercury is about the size of the Schwarschild *Radius* (SR) of the black hole, that is 0.4 AU. Your Wiki-link sais a distance larger than 3xSR allows stable circular orbits around the black hole. Our subject is teleported to about 7x that distance ! I repeat my question to you: what relativistic effects are you talking about, assuming v0=0 ? Please take into consideration we're talking about 10 AU, that is about the orbit of Saturn.

Comment: @Goodies {part 1} my comment was meant to be should relativistic effects be considered, as the Schwarzschild Radius is 0.08AU (*within the orbit of mercury*) and is ~20 times the radius of the sun. 
  

Now the suns Schwarzschild  radius is ~3km and the orbital radius of mercury is ~57,000,000km, so orbits at ~19,000,000 SR and at that distance it still experiences relativistic effects  [sufficient to be a test for relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tests_of_general_relativity) (precession of its orbit)

Comment: @Goodies {part 2}
In the question, the person is at 125 SR so I wasn’t sure it there would be any relativistic effects that need to be considered. Time at that distance runs ~1% slower than it does in empty space, and lengths are ~5% longer, again compared to empty space; at that distance the curvature is more than enough to [bent light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tests_of_general_relativity) (that was at ~$10^5$ SR).

Comment: @Goodies {part 3} So, I felt that there might be some effects as the person is moderately close to black hole, well within the range where there noticeable deviation from Newtonian gravity and general relativity.

Comment: @Nyra the clue of my answer is gravity is *not noticed*. The person is in free fall. Only when tidal force difference are relevant to a human-size body, it would influence the person, but that only happens at 1000s of G's and much nearer.. I don't think the perceived G as a result of your relativistic correction would be anything near dangerous.. See also HME's answer above. I rest my case, please end the discussion.